# trapping HUP/SIGHUP is not working in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, signals, trap, sighup

I have this bash script:
https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/06dbb26a48d2ddf48a5a2166834e0836

when I call `ql_acquire_lock` in a shell, if I can call `mkdir` on a directory, then I acquire that lock. When I call `ql_release_lock`, it removes that directory, simple stuff.

Now, when `ql_acquire_lock` is called, it calls:

trap ql_on_trap EXIT
trap ql_on_trap SIGHUP
trap ql_on_trap 0

if any of those signals are received, in theory, then `ql_release_lock` will get called:

the **problem I have** is when I close a terminal window, my script does NOT capture the SIGHUP or 0 signal. When the user issues SIGINT, my `trap` is invoked, most certainly by EXIT. But when the user closes the terminal window (I believe that should send a SIGHUP) my script's `trap` does not capture the signal. Anyone know why that would be?

Comment: If your trap is writing a message to the dead terminal perhaps it gets another signal and dies.

Comment: If I am closing the terminal window with the close/x button what other signal would it receive before SIGHUP? I also heard that `trap x 0` was sort of a catchall, and would therefore always be invoked.

Comment: I was thinking of what might happen if the sighup trap starts to run, then gets killed by something like sigpipe if it writes to some file descriptor towards another process that also dies with the window. trap 0 and trap exit are the same. Your `ql_on_trap` will be called by the sighup and again by the exit. Is that ok? Try adding `set -x` to the script and redirecting stderr to a file so you can see what might be happening.